# Dynamic 2-dimensional orthogonal range reporting in external memory and linear space

Tags: cg.comp-geom, ds.data-structures

Orthogonal 2-dimensional range reporting is the problem of storing a set of values from $U \times V$, where $U$ and $V$ are totally ordered universes, subject to queries of the form "Return all stored points in the four-sided box $[a,b] \times [c,d]$", where $a,b \in U$ and $c,d \in V$ are parameters of the query.

Nekrich, in ["Orthogonal range searching in linear and almost-linear space
"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.comgeo.2008.09.001), summarizes the best known results for linear space:

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline \text{Reference} & \text{Query Time} & \text{Modification Time} \\
\hline \text{Kreveld and Overmars} & O(\sqrt{n \lg n} + k) & O(\lg n)\\
\hline \text{Chazelle} & O((k+1)\lg^2 n) & O(\lg^2 n)\\
\hline \text{Nekrich} & O(\lg n + k \lg^\varepsilon n) & O(\lg^{3+\varepsilon} n) \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

- [Kreveld and Overmars, "Divided K-d trees"](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1988/1988-28.pdf)
- [Chazelle, "A functional approach to data structures and its use in multidimensional searching"](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/FunctionalDataStructures.pdf)
- [Nekrich, "Orthogonal range searching in linear and almost-linear space
  "](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.comgeo.2008.09.001)

What are the best known extensions of these in external memory? The result from [Arge et al.'s "On two-dimensional indexability and optimal range search indexing"](http://cs.au.dk/~large/Papers/rangepods99.pdf) uses superlinear space. The only generalizations I know have bounds

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline \text{Reference} & \text{Query Time} & \text{Modification Time} \\
\hline \text{Kanth and Singh} & O(\sqrt{n/B} + k/B) & O(\lg_B n)\\
\hline \text{Procopiuc et al.} & O(\sqrt{n/B} + k/B) & O\left(\frac{1}{B} \left( \lg_{M/B} \frac{n}{B}\right) \left(\lg \frac{n}{M}\right)\right)\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

- [Kanth and Singh, "Optimal dynamic range searching in non-replicating index structures"](http://cs.au.dk/~large/ioS05/KS.pdf)
- [Procopiuc et al., "Bkd-tree: A Dynamic Scalable kd-tree"](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~pankaj/publications/papers/bkd-sstd.pdf)